# Deploy PyQt5 applications on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyqt, setuptools

I recently wrote a small pyqt(python 3 and pyqt5) application for my biology class to simulate alleles fixation. I tried setuptools and indeed did produce a tarball package. However, I am not able to add PyQt5 as a dependency to my package possibly because it is no longer a package in PyPI. Consequently, when I install the program on another Linux PC, the program simply cannot execute because it is missing PyQt5 module. I tried this to add an official link in setup.py but it does not work either.

dependency_links = ['https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5'],

I installed pyqt binding from my distribution's official repository so I thought about to write a dependencies resolver script but since most Linux distributions have different package managers and package names, it will not be very feasible.

Is there a way to get around this?

Thank you!
Link to the app: https://github.com/lorix-lpan/alleles-fixation

Comment: just add in the installation instructions an analog of `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5` for your Linux distribution.

Comment: I wrote a small bash script to solve this kind of problem https://github.com/lorix-lpan/resolve-them It's reusable btw ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Installed python3-devel, python3-qt5, python3-setuptools, python3-sip (PCLinuxOS.)

Similar packages are available with the latest Fedora, Debian + the Debian clones (Ubuntu etc.)

( `$ sudo apt-get install python3-all-dev pyqt5-dev python3-pyqt5 python3-setuptools python3-sip` )

And : `$ cd alleles-fixation/ && python3 setup.py build` : No errors.

---